# PySpark Sum calculation within a date range

Tags: pyspark, window-functions

I have a `pyspark.DataFrame` like below, with columns `id`, `year` and `money`. Here for simplicity, I have taken only one `id` but there could be multiples.

```
id    year    money

1      2019    10

1      2018    15

1      2013    13

1      2009    10

1      2015    10

1      2014    11
```

In the resultant `DataFrame` for each `id` and period I want the sum of money for previous 3 consecutive years excluding the record year.

For example, for the year 2019, I want to take the sum of `money` for 2018, 2017 and 2016 only.
Since we only have 2018, the sum would be 15.

Another case like for the year 2015, I want to take the sum of `money` for 2014, 2013 and 2012. Since only the first 2 are present, it would sum to 24.

The resulting `DataFrame` would look like below.

```
id     year    sum_money     

1      2019      15   

1      2018      10

1      2015      24

1      2014      13

1      2013      0

1      2009      0
```

How can I achieve the desired results. Does the `lag` function provide any such functionality to look for only those years i want, or is there any other approach.

---

**My Approach**

My approach is taking the cum sum over the years, ordered by years in descending. Then for each id and year, find the maximum year which is just less than expected - window.

Say for the year 2019 and `window = 3`, the start year would be 2016. So the minimum year present in the dataset, which is 2015, is what we have to take. Corresponding to 2015 fill the cum_sum for that year.

Then in the final result column take the difference of two cum sum and value of current year sum. So for 2019 it would be 69 - 44 - 10 = 15. Same for other records(`id` & `year`) as well. Final data would look like below.

```
id    year    money   cum_sum     min_year    res_sum    diff
1      2019    10         69        2015        44        15
1      2018    15         59        2014        34        10
1      2015    10         44        2009        10        24
1      2014    11         34        2009        10        13
1      2013    13         23        2009        10        0
1      2009    10         10        0            0        0
```

I am trying to figure out a simpler approach.

Comment: see `rangeBetween` in window.

Comment: @samkart I can see some S.O articles with rangeBetween approach, but i can see they are specific to timestamp. Do I need to convert year to timestamp time. Something like 2019-01-01-00:00:00, and take days difference? will it also take leap year in consideration ?

Comment: Add code that you have tried and the difference to the expected output

Comment: yes, you'd have to convert the year to a timestamp and then use `interval`.

Comment: @SebastianWozny  I am still figuring out the approach. Say if 2019 is replaced by 2019-Q2, and then we have to look back where we have year as well as quarter, how can we do. My approach is with join and running sum order by Period(either year or year quarter)

Comment: @samkart let's say we have year as well quarter. Like 2019-Q2 and so on, and we want to look back. How can we do in that case. we cannot convert to timestamp. I am trying to figure out a generalize approach.

Comment: @milky_way I had to install pyspark, but I learned how to do the `rangeBetween` thing :)

Comment: @SebastianWozny thanks. Rangebetween is a nice solution. 
I have one question, if say our period is of type 2019-Q2, 2019-Q1.. I mean we have year-quarter, and I want to lookback, how can we do. Running sum (one i described above) can be followed i think. any other approach.

Comment: I added a solution that works with quarters :)

Comment: I went down the rabbithole of trying to convert quarters to datetime and using time windows but... honestly i'm not sure it's worth it.

Comment: @SebastianWozny As RangeBetween function provides us the capability to create a window on range of values and not on row number only. I think the solution which you have mentioned below is best and simple. 
Till now i was thinking that rangebetween creates windows between rows, but it creates on values also as you shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pyspark` we can use `rangeBetween` as pointed out by @samkart:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


data = [
    {'id': 1, 'year': 2019, 'money': 10},
    {'id': 1, 'year': 2018, 'money': 15},
    {'id': 1, 'year': 2013, 'money': 13},
    {'id': 1, 'year': 2009, 'money': 10},
    {'id': 1, 'year': 2015, 'money': 10},
    {'id': 1, 'year': 2014, 'money': 11}
]

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

# Calculate the sum over the preceding 3 years
window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("year").rangeBetween(-3, -1)
df = df.withColumn("previous_3_years_sum", sum("money").over(window))
df = df.fillna(0, subset=["previous_3_years_sum"])
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+----+--------------------+
| id|money|year|previous_3_years_sum|
+---+-----+----+--------------------+
|  1|   10|2009|                   0|
|  1|   13|2013|                   0|
|  1|   11|2014|                  13|
|  1|   10|2015|                  24|
|  1|   15|2018|                  10|
|  1|   10|2019|                  15|
+---+-----+----+--------------------+
```

This solution also strikes me as much more elegant. Window specs are pretty flexible and powerful. We don't need to create fake entries and no shifting etc is necessary. Initially I provided a solution using  `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'year': [2019, 2018, 2013, 2009, 2015, 2014],
    'money': [10, 15, 13, 10, 10, 11]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Fill in the missing years with 0s
df.set_index('year', inplace=True)
min_year = df.index.min()
max_year = df.index.max()
all_years = range(min_year, max_year + 1)
df = df.reindex(all_years).fillna(0)
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'year'})

#Sort by years, then cumsum shift by 3, diff and shift again to align the df
df=df.sort_values('year')
df['cum']=df.money.cumsum()
df['previous_3_years_sum']=(df.cum -df.cum.shift(3)).shift(1).fillna(0)
df=df.query('money>0')[['id','year','previous_3_years_sum']] #Filter for artifically inserted entries again
df
```

Output:

```
    id  year    previous_3_years_sum
0   1.0 2009    0.0
4   1.0 2013    0.0
5   1.0 2014    13.0
6   1.0 2015    24.0
9   1.0 2018    10.0
10  1.0 2019    15.0
```

EDIT:

I think the real question is about getting it for quarter specific reports. I solved this with a mapping. We multiply the year column by 4 to make space for 4 quarters: 2000 is mapped to 8000, and 8000 now represents Q1,8001 Q2 etc. Then we can use `rangeBetween` for 12 quarters.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace


# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Create the data
data = [
    (1, 10, "2009-Q1"),
    (1, 13, "2013-Q1"),
    (1, 11, "2014-Q1"),
    (1, 10, "2015-Q1"),
    (1, 15, "2018-Q1"),
    (1, 10, "2019-Q1")
]

# Create the DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "money", "quarter"])


# Split the quarter column into year and quarter columns
df = df.withColumn("year", split(df["quarter"], "-").getItem(0))
df = df.withColumn("quarter", split(df["quarter"], "-").getItem(1))
df = df.withColumn("quarter", regexp_replace(df["quarter"], "Q", "").cast("int"))
# Add a new column for the calculated value
df = df.withColumn("new_column", (df["year"] * 4) + (df["quarter"] - 1).cast("int"))
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("new_column").rangeBetween(-12, -1)
df = df.withColumn("previous_3_years_sum", sum("money").over(window_spec))

# Fill null values with 0
df = df.fillna(0, subset=["previous_3_years_sum"])
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+-------+----+----------+--------------------+
| id|money|quarter|year|new_column|previous_3_years_sum|
+---+-----+-------+----+----------+--------------------+
|  1|   10|      1|2009|    8036.0|                   0|
|  1|   13|      1|2013|    8052.0|                   0|
|  1|   11|      1|2014|    8056.0|                  13|
|  1|   10|      1|2015|    8060.0|                  24|
|  1|   15|      1|2018|    8072.0|                  10|
|  1|   10|      1|2019|    8076.0|                  15|
+---+-----+-------+----+----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I shared my approach above. Please review and suggest. Also mocking years is another good solution.

Comment: This Rangebetween with you mapping solution is just great. I can even do for half yearly data, keeping multiplicative factor as 2

Comment: For those who require proof, like why we keep multiplicative factor as 4 in qtr. Here is below
For the rangebetween to be used as expected, we need the difference of 1 between each  consecutive period. 
Let's say we have one period as 2019-Q1 and other as 2018-Q4.
So we want to make sure that the difference of the values we map to them should be 1
Let k be the multiplicative factor. 
2018 * k + 4(for q4) = 2019 * k + 1(for q1) - 1(bcoz we want difference as 1)

2018k + 4 = 2018k + k + 1 - 1 
k = 4. Similarly we can take other examples, and conclude that k will be 4 in case of quarters.